# 同一npmパッケージ名の複数のバージョンをサブディレクトリにインストールすることはできますか?

Tags: javascript, node.js

具体的にはAngularJSのインストールについてなのですが、各サブディレクトリ内で`npm i angular@1.3.15`と`npm i angular@1.4.0-rc.0`を実行しても、全てルートの`./node_modules`に入ってしまいます。

```
.
├── node_modules <-ここに入ってしまう
├── package.json
└── test
    ├── 1-3-15
    │   └── node_modules <- こっちに入れたい
    └── 1-4-0
        └── node_modules <- こっちに入れたい
```

`./package.json`のdependencies, devDependenciesに追記される必要はありません。また、インストールされるファイル構成が`npm i`した時と同じになる方法ならば`npm`を使わなくても構いません。何か方法はありますでしょうか。

OS X 10.9.5, iojs v1.6.2, npm 2.7.5

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。インストールしたいディレクトリ内で

```
mkdir node_modules && cd $_ && npm i angular@1.3.15
```

をするだけで可能でした。